# Enzyme - how to test that a child receives context

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have a context provider and I want to test it provides some value (let's say `foo`) via context to its children. How can I do this with Enzyme? Is this even possible?

```
<MyContextProvider>
    <Child />  // how do I test that foo is available in the Child component's context?
</MyContextProvider>
```

Update: I want to test this because I pass a prop to my context provider, which is then provided as part of the context object.

```
const store = configureStore()({ locale: 'es' });
const wrapper = mount(
    <ConnectedIntlProvider store={store}>
        <Child />
    </ConnectedIntlProvider>
);
```

I want to test that ConnectedIntlProvider obtains `locale` from the store and then passes it as part of `intl` object via context to its children.

Update 2:
I managed to write the test without using Enzyme. It looks a bit odd though, I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to achieve the same result using Enzyme.

```
it('uses locale from store', () => {
    class Child extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <div />;
        }
    }

    Child.contextTypes = {
        intl: intlShape,
    };

    const store = configureStore()({ locale: 'es' });
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    let child;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ConnectedIntlProvider store={store}>
            <Child
                ref={(c) => {
                    child = c;
                }}
            />
        </ConnectedIntlProvider>,
        div
    );
    const locale = child && child.context && child.context.intl && child.context.intl.locale;
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    expect(locale).toEqual('es');
});
```

Comment: I'd say that is something that you do not need to test at all as this is already extensively tested in the react library.

Comment: Please see my update to the question.